# Order by second set of Numbers in Mysql Column?

Tags: mysql

So I know how to sort a mixed column of numbers, i.e.

```
A1, A2, A3
```

My question is if it had a mixed set of numbers i.e.

```
Name_01022017_number-001
```

How would I go about sorting by that second number set and not the first set? I'd rather sort by that number than the date. Thanks.

Comment: Could you please provide some query you are referencing to?

Comment: @stackFan Say I am doing this to get that second example. 'Select CNum FROM table;'

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:
`SELECT CAST('123abc' AS UNSIGNED) AS fieldname;`
and `ORDER BY fieldname`

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to use the substring function to get the number or string you want to sort with. I assume that you want to use 001 in this case

```
select * from table order by substring(column, start position, len)
```

Comment: What if the substring length can change? I.e. that first number could be like 01012017 or 112017?

Comment: In this case, you cannot use this one I sent. Use the one below. Use position function to find "-" and use it. It would be something like this select * from table order by substring(column, position("-" in columnName), len)